# AttributeError: module 'librosa.filters' has no attribute 'dct' for PNCC speech feature extraction

Tags: python

I am trying to use a piece of code available here https://github.com/supikiti/PNCC/blob/master/pncc.py

for feature extraction.
I got below error.

```
dct = np.dot(power_law_nonlinearity, filters.dct(
AttributeError: module 'librosa.filters' has no attribute 'dct'
```

I am using following code to execute the pncc function.

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
from pncc import pncc

(rate,audio_wav) = wav.read("EV_M_01_Anger.wav")

print("\nRate is ",rate)

pncc_features=pncc(audio_wav)

print('printing pncc features',pncc_features)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because you are using a newer version of `librosa`.

Looking through the docs, `librosa 0.6.0` had discrete cosign transform ([dct](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/LibROSA.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/generated/librosa.filters.dct.html)) as a filter.

However, [`version 0.8.0`](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/filters.html#filter-bank-construction) no longer has this filter available.

It appears they now utilize SciPy's DCT function.